# String indices must be integers when i used an api code

Tags: python, json, pandas

I use parsehub to extract data from a url. I have successfully extracted the data and I load it into a json file. Now I am trying to access some fields in the json file but I am having 'string indices must be integer' error. Can someone tell me what mistake I did in my codes?

```py
params = {
  "api_key": "tb7Q6fd2VVJJ",
  "format": "json"
}
r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/runs/ttx8PT-EL6Rf/data', params=params)
json = r.text
print(json)
new_data = {'selection1': []}
for item in json['selection1']:
    if 'reviews' in item:
        print(item['reviews'])

        # save in file
        with open('output2.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(new_data, f)

selection1 = new_data['selection1']
for item in selection1:
    name = item['name']
    #print ('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', name)
    Date = item['reviews']
    for d in Date:
        #convert date from 'january 12, 2020' to 2020-01-02
        date = pd.to_datetime(d['date']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

        #print('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ', date)
    CommentID = item['reviews']
    for com in CommentID:
        comment = com['review']
        lcomment = comment.lower()  # converting all to lowercase
        result = re.sub(r'\d+', '', lcomment)  # remove numbers
        results = (result.translate(
        str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).strip()  # remove punctuations and white spaces
        comments = remove_stopwords(results)
        print('>>>>>>',comments)
```

Below is part of my json file:

```
{
 "selection1": [
  {
   "name": "Radisson Blu Azuri Resort & Spa",
   "url": "https://www.marideal.mu/hotel-deals/radisson-blu-azuri-resort-hotel-deals.html",
   "CommentID": [
    {
     "name": "137",
     "Date": "February 02, 2020",
     "comment": "I enjoy the daily package from the start with the welcoming up to the end.\nI recommend this hotel."
    },
    {
     "name": "136",
     "Date": "September 07, 2019",
     "comment": "enjoy a lovely moment"
    },
    {
     "name": "135",
     "Date": "July 15, 2019",
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
     "Date": "September 18, 2015",
     "comment": "At the desk, they don’t give any information at all when you check-in (like at what time breakfast is served, you have to guess) or promoting the hotel; communication is very scarce. It’d have been better to do your own check-in. For a 5* hotel, English is very poor except when you call over the phone. We asked a question in English at the reception desk, one of them stepped back & the other one asked if we speak French. Overall ok, very nice hotel but room standard more of a 4 star hotel ,swimming pool funny. The men carrying the Luggage, and on car park duty were friendly & the food at the Yusu restaurant is good"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/EmotionAnalysis/api.py", line 69, in <module>
    for item in json['selection1']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `json = r.text` should be `json = r.json`

Comment: I have just tried it sir but I am having this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvbBw.png

Comment: Sorry, should be `r.json()`

Comment: I got no errors but it is not printing the comments..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIF2s.png this is the result I got

Comment: what do I need to do for the comments to be printed sir?

Comment: You never add anything to `new_data['selection1']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209174/discussion-between-nedisha-and-barmar).